# String or binary data would be truncated for SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL function which returns an error when column is passed. It throws an error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I have tried changing the length in function but no luck. Please assist.

The function checks if column contains Japanese numbers which are stored in another table.

I have changed the length from 100 to max but no luck.

```
create function [dbo].[NonEnglishJapanese_Confirmity]
    (@String nvarchar(100))
returns nvarchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @Y nvarchar(100), @Z nvarchar(100), 
            @resultset as nvarchar(100)
    set @y = @String 

    set @Z = (select cast(Comma_delimited as nvarchar(100)) 
              from [dbo].[DelimitwithComma](@Y))
    -- print @z

    --select @Z
    set @resultset = (select 'Letters Missing' 
                      from 
                          (select count(*) coun  
                           from 
                               (select a.[Value] 
                                from FnSplit(@Z,',') a 
                                join [non-english Characters] b on a.[value] = b.Japanese
                               ) x
                          ) y 
                      where coun = len(@Y)
                     ) 
    return @resultset
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSiLl.jpg)

Comment: We can't really help much here because you have at least two functions that we don't have code for. But this function also has a major problem. Once you figure out the truncation issue it always going to return the string literal 'Letters Missing'.

Comment: Thanks for comment .that's the issue it should not throw an error as it will return only 'letter missing'.This is the only code i have. It will only return 'Letters missing' if all condition met else it will be blank. I am not sure what am i missing but have been struggling a lot.

Comment: Error info contains line number. What is it?

Comment: The error is almost certainly happening somewhere in the code we can't see (hint...those two functions you have). To be honest this seems it could be rewritten to make this a lot less complicated. It seems you are first delimiting a string and then splitting it again.

Comment: Ivan I have attached the screen shot please check

Comment: Please don't post **pictures of text**. Did you check what is `max(len())` of column from screenshot?

Comment: max(len)) is 30 and datalength is 60

Comment: Very well. Continue debugging. There are no obvious issues in the _shown_ code.

Comment: You need to post the definition of those two functions. Then the value you are passing in here. But to be honest it seems this whole bunch of stuff could be replaced with a single query using EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. I have figured it out, In one of the functions data length was inadequate. Fixed It...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change length of   `@resultset as nvarchar(100)` to max. i.e. `@resultset as nvarchar(max)`

In above query  I have mention to change the length of the variable to max.

Comment: `set @resultset = (select 'Letters Missing' `

Comment: No Luck with above change

Comment: What are you trying to say Ivan Starostin

Comment: I have a function [dbo].[DelimitwithComma] in my function [dbo].[NonEnglishJapanese_Confirmity]. this function is to split the string and the length of the split string was 100 which was not enough. That caused the error...

Comment: Well done. Finally you were able to resolve the issue. :)